# Bootstrap date range picker styling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem on styling  my form which uses bootstrap date range picker dropdown.

Here are two images that what i want and how my page look like:

This is the screenshot for what I did:
[image]

And here is what i want the form to look like:
[image]

This is the code for form that i created:

```
<div class="form-group" style="border: 1px solid">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Period
              </label>
              </div>
              <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date Range</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use col-md-* class of bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group" style="border: 1px solid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="radio">
               <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Period</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
             <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date Range</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going out on a limb here, and if you included a fiddle it would make helping you easier, but my initial guess would be that you *probably* want to throw the contents of your `form-group` into a row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group" style="border: 1px solid">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Period
              </label>
              </div>
              <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Select Date Range</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```